# Actuator unit test not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito, spring-boot-actuator

Trying to test the /health.json endpoint for the actuator for when the status is Up or DOWN.

```
public class ActuatorTest
{

  @TestConfiguration
  static class Config
  {
      @Bean
      public HealthIndicator dbHealthIndicator()
      {
          return Mockito.mock(HealthIndicator.class);
      }
  }

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mvc;

  @Autowired
  private HealthIndicator dbHealthIndicator;

  @Test
  public void healthcheck_Up() throws Exception
  {
      when(dbHealthIndicator.health()).thenReturn(Health.status(Status.UP).build());

      mvc.perform(get("/health.json"))
              .andExpect(status().isOk())
              .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
              .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value("UP"));

  }

  @Test
  public void healthcheck_Down() throws Exception
  {
      when(dbHealthIndicator.health()).thenReturn(Health.status(Status.DOWN).build());

      mvc.perform(get("/health.json"))
              .andExpect(status().isServiceUnavailable())
              .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
              .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value("DOWN"));

  }
}
```

the test for when the status is down always gives a status of 200 when infact it should be a 503.

Comment: Show where you actually set the status to 503. 
You make a get which returns 200 OK, as long as you don't set the status to 503 somewhere.

Comment: @Arigion the healthcheck_Down() test, should give a 503. As the healthindicator status is set to DOWN

Comment: Curious why you would be unit testing Spring Boot's Actuator yourself and not trusting the tests within Spring Actuator project itself, sounds like duplication of effort if you are not customising any of it. Irregardless are you positive that the mocking you are doing it working as expected? That the MockMVC will map correctly to the /health endpoint and is using your mock bean as expected?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe If I run the healthcheck_Down test by itself it works. But If I run ActuatorTest it fails. Seems like the when statement in the healthcheck_Down doesnt have any effect. And it still returns a 200 OK and a status of UP.